# Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator check_and_cast error

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm new in OMNeT++. I have a problem when run these codes.
The error is as follows:

> check_and_cast(): Cannot cast (inet::Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator*)Network.configurator to type 'inet::Ipv4NetworkConfigurator *' -- in module (inet::Ipv4NodeConfigurator) Network.Host.ipv4.configurator (id=32), during network initialization

Comment: Welcome at SO! Could you be so kind and provide [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

(You can see the fixed code of the package added at the end of the message.)

I believe that you were trying to create this kind of structure at your design:

[image]

and I will assume that you tried to use Ipv4FlatNetworkConfigurator or Ipv6FlatNetworkConfigurator. However, routers and hosts of the network at this design are actually used Ipv4NetworkConfigurator. Since you want to have an Internet Protocol Configurator. You have to use Ipv4NetworkConfigurator because they are actually different kinds of types which are Ipv4**Flat**NetworkConfigurator and Ipv4NetworkConfigurator. Therefore, you have to apply your configurator as Ipv4NetworkConfigurator. As you can see from the image design of the package, I used Ipv4NetworkConfigurator:

[image]

Also, I want to show you which place is having type casting problems:

[image]

This is the place that routers and hosts are defined configurations for Internet Protocol. As you see from line 8, it is actually Ipv4NetworkConfigurator. When you set the configuration of your network as Ip4**Flat**NetworkConfigurator, you actually said that I want to use them as Flat type. However, they are not actually implemented as Flat types.

```
package {yourprojectname}.simulations;

import inet.examples.inet.ipv4hook.MyHost;
import inet.examples.inet.ipv4hook.MyRouter;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth100M;


@license(LGPL);
//
// TODO documentation
//
network Network
{
    @display("bgb=643,441");
    submodules:
        Server: MyHost {
            @display("p=555,157;b=10,5");
        }
        Host: MyHost {
            @display("p=69,202");
        }
        Router: MyRouter {
            @display("p=315,202");
        }

        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=488,61");
        }
    connections:
        Host.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> Router.ethg++;
        Server.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> Router.ethg++;
}
```